# Finding one element in graphQL by id/email

Tags: javascript, express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm trying to make a findOneByEmail/id for graphQL. I saw a couple of questions, blog posts, and videos, but they didn't help my case. I know I have to add a filter, but I have to be missing something

Here are my `resolvers`

```
const users = [
  {id: 1, email:'a@a.a',password:'zaq1@WSX', pons:[{value:'test'}]},
  {id: 2, email:'b@b.b',password:'ZAQ!2wsx', pons:[{value:'tset'}]}
];
const pons = [{value: 'test'}];
module.exports = {
  Query: {
    users: () => users,
    pons: () => pons,
  }
};
```

`typeDefs`

```
const {gql} = require('apollo-server-express');

module.exports = gql`  
  type Pon {
      value: String!
  }
  type User {
    id: Int
    email: String!
    password: String!
    pons: [Pon]!
  }
  type Query {
      findUser(id: Int): [User]
      users: [User]
      pons: [Pon]
  }
`;
```

`app.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const typeDefs = require('./graphql/typeDefs.js');
const resolvers = require('./graphql/resolvers.js');

const server = new ApolloServer({typeDefs, resolvers});

const app = express();
server.applyMiddleware({ app });

app.listen({ port: 4000 }, () =>
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`)
);
```

I am using `express` with `apollo-server-express`.

I tried adding `users(id: Int)` and `users(email: String)`, but with no success. You can see it in `findUser` query. I am calling the query like:

```
query{
  findUser(id: 1) {
    email
    pons {
      value
    }
  }
}
```

In the GQL playground.

I'd like to able to filter the data on the server, not on the client, and can't find the solution anywhere

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#handling-arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the `id` parameters in GraphQL resolver and query user by it.

E.g.

```js
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const { gql } = require('apollo-server-express');

const users = [
  { id: 1, email: 'a@a.a', password: 'zaq1@WSX', pons: [{ value: 'test' }] },
  { id: 2, email: 'b@b.b', password: 'ZAQ!2wsx', pons: [{ value: 'tset' }] },
];
const pons = [{ value: 'test' }];

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Pon {
    value: String!
  }
  type User {
    id: Int
    email: String!
    password: String!
    pons: [Pon]!
  }
  type Query {
    findUser(id: Int): User
    users: [User]
    pons: [Pon]
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    users: () => users,
    pons: () => pons,
    findUser: (_, { id }) => users.find((u) => u.id === id),
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

const app = express();
server.applyMiddleware({ app });

app.listen({ port: 4000 }, () => console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`));
```

query in GraphQL playground:

```js
query{
  findUser(id: 1){
    email 
    pons {
      value
    }
  }
}
```

response:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "findUser": {
      "email": "a@a.a",
      "pons": [
        {
          "value": "test"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's the `_` in `findUser` Query?

Comment: @AlexIronside The second argument of resolver, the `{id}`

Comment: Ok so I just needed to add the find and comparison in resolver?

Comment: @AlexIronside For the real world, you should find the user from your database using the `id`  parameter. But for this example, we have a memory database `users`. So, yes, you just need to find the user from this `users` array.